# Selenium Java, how to get second text that wrapped double quotes?

Tags: java, selenium

I got this web page to test whether this element contains a certain keyword in it.

```
<div>
"&nbsp;"
"Network interface updated successfully"
</div>
```

This is the HTML code and the xpath I am trying to get is

```
//div[contains(text(),'interface')]
```

But this xpath doesn't find this element at all. So I tried different way to figure out how it works.

```
//div/text()[2]
```

This xpath matches up the element, but it is not the best practice for me.

I attached the screen shot what I am suffering.....
[image]

Comment: when you try xpath, how many elements you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found Something similar to your example here
[image]

now if you want the entire text enclosed within that element and you dont want to index through the scripts you can do it via java script executor
[image]

run the below statement with java script executor and it will return the entire text, once you fetch the text you can assert if it contains the expected text.

'return $x("//div[@class='jconfirm-content']//div//div")[0].textContent'

Comment: If the text is one line, it matches up the xpath, but the web application I am looking at is two lines. It looks like an array. That's why it matches xpath //div/text()[2]

Comment: I added a GIF screenshot, so you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: i have update my answer with the similar example as yours you can have a look and see if  it works for you

Answer (score 0):

if you are so sure about 2nd element has the text. please use following code.

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your xpath"));
String secondTxt = rows.get(1).getText();
```

element index startswith 0, so following are the matching
0th element contains 1st text
1st element contains 2nd text

> if text index is changing on each runtime, you should not get text based on index. you should iterate every element and get the text.

Comment: Well, the reason I want to get the element xpath is that I will use this xpath as a Locator. So it should be valid xpath for .. until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath( ????? ) );

Comment: you cannot directly get the 2nd text since it has same text and double quotes so you should get via count. can you please try this one >>>> List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Network interface updated successfully"));
String secondTxt = rows.get(1).getText();

Answer (score 0):

Those are not **plain text** instead they are **text node**. If you apply `/text()` selenium will throw an error, cause it is not supported by **Selenium**, Please use `JavascriptExecutor`

**Code :**

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'jconfirm-content')]//child::div[1]"));
String el = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[1].textContent;", e);
System.out.println(el);
```

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I will study about that.